# Glossaries: page header title not upper-case

Tags: header-footer, glossaries

I am using default book template with glossaries included like this:

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\makeglossaries
```

Notice the `toc` option for adding the glossaries to the table of contents.

However, when I try to print the entries with the following command:

```
\printglossary[title=Seznam oznak]
```

The page header is *NOT* upper-cased like other page headers. This is how the header looks like:

[image]

If I change the `\printglossary` command to this:

```
\printglossary[title=Seznam oznak,toctitle=SEZNAM OZNAK]
```

Then the header is displayed OK. *BUT* the upper-cased text is also displayed in the table of contents - which I don't want.

**Question**: How to properly use `glossaries` so that it displays `Seznam oznak` in the table of contents and as the page title. And that it displays `SEZNAM OZNAK` as the page header on the second page of glossaries entries (I only have two pages worth of entries).

Comment: Try the package option `ucmark`.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick! Please make an answer from this comment so I can award you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glossaries` package has a boolean option `ucmark` which, if set, applies uppercasing to the page header (via the `\glsglossarymark` command). This option is `false` by default unless the `memoir` class has been loaded.